# Can I support only arm64-v8a in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, arm64

I am working on Android app with native libraries and I don`t want to support 32-bit phones. Can I avoid **armeabi-v7a** and support only one ABI - **arm64-v8a**.
In Google web page is written that the apps must support 64-bit ABIs, but nowhere is written can you drop the support for 32-bit apps - https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/64-bit

So can I upload app on Google Play which support only arm64-v8a?

```
abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
```

Comment: Does anyone know?